# How to get value from Arraybuffer of BLE device read characteristic value

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

I have gone through doc of IONIC 2 whcih is https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/ble/ . From there conversion of arraybuffer to string is given which is not working for me . As shown in image [image]

How to get firmware version from this data from read characteristics as Arraybuffer conversion code of IONIC 2 which is:
 `function bytesToString(buffer) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
}`
is not working for me. Using that code I am getting output: `îÍy}ùt`. I am new to ionic . I have Byte Transmission Order least significant octet first (i.e., little endian). please provide me conversion solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `bytesToString` also and also got the value in ascii afterwards i did this:

```
var convertData = bytesToString(result);
var hexResult = [];

for (var i=0; i < convertData.length; i++){
   var resultNumber = convertData.charCodeAt(i);   //Dec
   var resultString = ("00" + (+resultNumber).toString(16)).substr(-2); //String
   hexResult[i] = "0x" + resultString;
}
```

I want hex so I did `toString(16)`. You can change accordingly and play around with this.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem, however the simple solution i found is `let data=new Uint8Array(buffer)`
now in `data` you will get all values in array.